# Why was Chirrut obsessed with Force chants?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, Chirrut was obsessed with Force chants. He was always babbling about the Force. Why was Chirrut obsessed with Force chants?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  "addicted" and "babble" are somewhat negatively loaded words; I think the appropriate term would be "[affirmations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmations_(New_Age))."

Comment: @DavidW -- Contrasting opinion: 1. this is a fictional character, not a real person, so there is no attack or insult here; and 2. as we see in the answer, Baze himself calls Chirrut a "fool", so terms like addicted and babble are perfectly applicable and neutral in context. We shouldn't take these things too personally!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chirrut Imwe was a Guardian of the Temple of the Whills, so he was a devotee of the religion of the Force and it would make sense that he would recite their mantras. Baze specifically points out that Chirrut is still devoted to the religion (in contrast to Baze's own apparently jaded opinion of it).

> There are no Jedi anymore, only dreamers like this fool.

It's also suggested in the movie (such as him knowing about about Jyn's necklace) that Chirrut is Force-sensitive, although presumably not to the degree necessary to be accepted as a Jedi. His recitation of the Jedi mantras is an audio cue that he is focusing himself on what Force abilities he has; such as to allow him to walk headlong into a barrage of blaster fire without getting shot.